# Update ionic framework from 3.7.0->3.7.1 can’t build ios app

Tags: ionic3

I am updating the framework from 3.7.0->3.7.1 recently.
When I using 3.7.0 to build tha app, everything is fine, but after I update the version to 3.7.1 when I run “ionic cordova platform add ios”, it have a following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './resources'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at /Users/xxxxxx/Downloads/ionicproj/node_modules/ionic/dist/commands/cordova/index.js:25:167
```

Anyone know how to solve it, thanks? my ionic info is below:

```
cli packages: (/Users/xxxxxx/Downloads/ionicproj/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.15.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.15.1 
global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 
local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.1
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.5.2
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1
System:

ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
ios-sim    : 5.0.13 
Node       : v7.10.0
npm        : 5.0.4 
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.0.1 Build version 9A1004 
Environment Variables:

ANDROID_HOME : not set
Misc:

backend : legacy
```

Here is the package.json (sorry a little bit long):

```
{
  "name": "ionicproj",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/action-sheet": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/badge": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^4.3.1",
    "@ionic-native/base64": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/brightness": "^4.3.1",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/crop": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/deeplinks": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/google-analytics": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/stripe": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.0.1",
    "com-badrit-base64": "^0.2.0",
    "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.2",
    "cordova-plugin-actionsheet": "^2.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.1",
    "cordova-plugin-brightness": "^0.1.5",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^2.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-cocoapod-support": "^1.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-crop": "^0.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-exitapp": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^1.9.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^4.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "git+https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase.git",
    "cordova-plugin-globalization": "^1.0.7",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-jcore": "^1.1.6",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-stripe": "^1.5.3",
    "cordova-plugin-swift-support": "^3.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.0.4",
    "cordova.custom.plugins.exitapp": "~1.0.0",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.7.1",
    "ionic-native": "^2.9.0",
    "ionic-plugin-deeplinks": "^1.0.15",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionic2-rating": "^1.2.2",
    "ionic3-jpush": "^1.1.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "jpush-phonegap-plugin": "git+https://github.com/jpush/jpush-phonegap-plugin.git",
    "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
    "node-gyp": "^3.6.2",
    "object-keys": "^1.0.11",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^6.0.8",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "ionic": "3.15.1",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-globalization": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova.custom.plugins.exitapp": {},
      "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
        "APP_ID": "2345674657938966",
        "APP_NAME": "xxx"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " ",
        "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
      },
      "cordova-plugin-actionsheet": {},
      "cordova-plugin-crop": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "jpush-phonegap-plugin": {
        "APP_KEY": "2344813132322a2fccbecd178f"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-badge": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "ionic-plugin-deeplinks": {
        "URL_SCHEME": "xxx",
        "DEEPLINK_SCHEME": "https",
        "DEEPLINK_HOST": "xxx.com",
        "ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "ANDROID_2_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "ANDROID_3_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "ANDROID_4_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "ANDROID_5_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
        "DEEPLINK_2_SCHEME": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_2_HOST": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_3_SCHEME": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_3_HOST": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_4_SCHEME": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_4_HOST": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_5_SCHEME": " ",
        "DEEPLINK_5_HOST": " "
      },
      "com-badrit-base64": {},
      "cordova-plugin-stripe": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebase": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": {
        "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
      },
      "cordova-plugin-brightness": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
   ]
 }
}
```

Comment: can you include your package.json in your question?

Comment: @SurajRao Thanks for your reply, I have posted the package.json. I am very distressed by this error, since everything fine when i am using old version.

Comment: `3.15.1` is the cli version not ionic framework version which is `3.7.1` by the way. What did you update?

Comment: @SurajRao Sorry for that, I have edit the post to change 3.15.1 to 3.7.1, I have updated the cli, uuid instead of node-uuid, object-keys, node-gyp, ionic 3.7.1 and cordova etc, because i am just follow the guide which ask me to update in the terminal

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases) you need to update zone.js to `0.8.18` your package.json has `0.8.12`

Comment: @SurajRao I have manually change the zone.js 0.8.12 to 0.8.18 in package.json, and remove the existing node_modules directory, and then run npm install, but the error still exist